# Best way to display a pdf cross browser

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, drop-down-menu, cross-browser

What is the best way to display a pdf on a web page in a cross browser manner ? I am targetting IE8+.
Additionnally, I need a solution that would allow for dropdown or popins to come over the pdf.

Comment: the best way is a hyperlink... eg. &lt;a href="document.pdf" target="_blank"&gt;document.pdf&lt;a&gt;

windows does not come with a pdf reader application pre-installed. with a hyperlink solution the visitor has the option to download the pdf document to their hard drive. MSIE has security settings for ActiveX and https sourced documents.

Comment: I'd need the second best way then, as I need to display, not download the document.

Comment: All embed or object or iframe content is downloaded to the cache.
It sounds like you have Internet Options>Advanced tab, "do not save encrypted files to disk" checked.
or

other - if using embed make sure you have type="application/pdf"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can use Google Docs Viewer to embed not just PDFs buts 12 other file formats including Excel & Powerpoint](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-display-word-excel-powerpoint.html).

To embed, you'll need to append the URL of the PDF to the *url* querystring of the Google Docs Viewer service. Here's an example -

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fviewer%3Furl%3
Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flabs.google.com%252Fpapers%252F
bigtable-osdi06.pdf&embedded=true" style="border: none;" 
height="780" width="600">
</iframe>
```

Update: Try using [Mozilla's PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) to display the PDF content. Its a PDF Reader in JavaScript

Comment: thanks but I can't rely on a third party service, as we are displaying sensitive data and have a layer of authentication to access the content

Comment: @mlarcher Try using Mozilla's PDF.js to display the PDF content. Its a PDF Reader in JavaScript

Comment: It does not support IE8, but it seems it might be my best option so far. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Google Docs Viewer is not supported anymore. You can use http://viewerjs.org/ or other viewers.

Comment: @raduanastase Not sure what you mean by "Google Docs Viewer is not supported". Though it is not relevant to OP, I've been using it on & off and it works as of today - https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ44.pdf